# How to grab current url and use it in load() function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to reload the content of the page I am on, so I am grabbing the div I want to reload of  the same page in url as I am currently on and it is working:

```
success : function(msg)
        {
            $('#div-to-reload').load('http://localhost/page-i-am-currently-on.php #div-to-reload');
        }
```

But I need it to be done dynamically so javascript find out the current URL and append it instead of the hardcoded url

> `http://localhost/page-i-am-currently-on.php`

.

I have tried this, but it is not working ;( :

```
success : function(msg)
        {
            var pathtopage = window.location.pathname;
            $('#div-to-reload').load('pathtopage #div-to-reload');}
```

Thanks in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but just a slight problem:

```
$('#div-to-reload').load(pathtopage + ' #div-to-reload');}
```

You had `pathtopage` in quotes, so it was treated as a string literal. You need to concatenate the value of `pathtopage` with the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href`:

```
var pathtopage = window.location.href;
$('#div-to-reload').load(pathtopage + '#div-to-reload');
```

Comment: In this case `pathname` should work too. The problem is just the fact that the variable identifier was quoted.